# Spacy/Gensim - creating similar sentences

Tags: gensim, spacy

I have around 1000 pairs of sentences. Each pair consists of two sentences, one causing high CTR and one LOW. I want to create a mechanism to auto-produce sentences optimized for high CTR. When iterating the pairs, I can get a vector (using Spacy NLP) for each sentence. I take the vectors difference (Sent1.vector - Sent2.Vector) and then mean all the pairs using numpy mean. When I have the "difference vector" in hand, I want to add it to any given text and get a new sentence. any Ideas how to obtain this? Gensim most_similar only works on single words... Thanks